# How to hide some elemens from a website for destop when trying to make this website for mobile using Media Queries

Tags: html, css

I have just done a website for destop, and now I am trying to make it possible for the website to work in mobile devices. I am using Media Queries. But I have a problem. I want to have some element special for my mobile wensite, and not to display these elements in the desktop website. When I  use display: none for those elements in the part of css file for desktop website , then the  elements disapper from mymobile website to...
Can anyone help me please. I have spends hours on these and nothing...

Comment: Use `display: none` in the general area and `display: block` in the media query.